# Thinkpad P14s AMD 2nd gen: suspend to RAM doesn't work

Tags: suspend, encryption, thinkpad, 21.04

I own the new [Thinkpad P14s AMD 2nd gen](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/coming-soon/P14s-AMD-G2/p/22WSP144SA2) with Ubuntu 21.04 and full disk encryption. It almost works out of the box except for Wi-Fi (that can be fixed with [this driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89)) and suspension.

Actually, I'm not totally sure where the problem is: if I try to suspend, all keyboard lights switch off, except for the power button that stays on. When I try to resume from suspension, keyboard lights switch on but the screen doesn't and I can do nothing except forcing the shut down by holding the power button.

Can the problem be related to full-disk encryption? Or maybe some kernel problem with this new laptop?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the issue, which wasn't related to disk encryption: this laptop has the S0 sleep mode activated by default, but Linux supports S3 (suspend to RAM).

To fix it, from BIOS → *Energy* switch the sleep mode from *Windows* (S0) to *Linux* (S3) and suspension to RAM starts working!